# Why does JavaScript's map() work but my for loop fails with React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, this, react-fullstack

I'm teaching myself React and I have come across something I am having trouble understanding. When I build my project with the code in getNavList() below I get the following error when clicking one of the buttons rendered in my  component, "cannot read property of undefined 'click' react."

```
export class Pane extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }

  getNavList() {
    var buttons = [];
    if(this.props.subNavButtons != null){
      for(var i = 0; i < this.props.navButtons.length; i++) {
        buttons.push(<Button onClick={this.props.navButtons[i].click()} title={this.props.navButtons[i].title} />);
        buttons.push(<Button onClick={this.props.navButtons[i + i].click()} title={this.props.navButtons[i + i].title} />);
        buttons.push(<Button onClick={this.props.navButtons[i + i + 1].click()} title={this.props.navButtons[i + i + 1].title} />);
      }
    } else {
      buttons = this.props.navButtons.map(button => (<Button onClick={() => button.click()} title={button.title}/>));
    }
    return buttons;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.getNavList()}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I build my project with the following changes, everything works as intended:

```
export class Pane extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

      }

      getNavList() {
        var buttons = [];
        if(this.props.subNavButtons != null){
          buttons = this.props.navButtons.map((button, index) => (<>
                                                                  <Button onClick={() => button.click()} title={button.title}/>
                                                                  <Button onClick={() => this.props.subNavButtons[index + index].click()} title={this.props.subNavButtons[index + index].title}/>
                                                                  <Button onClick={() => this.props.subNavButtons[index + index + 1].click()} title={this.props.subNavButtons[index + index + 1].title}/>
                                                                  </>));
        }
        else {
          buttons = this.props.navButtons.map(button => (<Button onClick={() => button.click()} title={button.title}/>));
        }
        return buttons;
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <ul>
              {this.getNavList()}
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

From what I've been able to find, it seems like there's an issue with 'this' losing it's context when I pass the function as a component property. I tried binding the function passed to the Pane object in its parent class to no avail. I also tried defining the function using arrow notation instead with no luck. With that being said, why is it that this change from a for loop to the map function work?

Here's a more minor issue within the same code snippet. With the working getNavList() I return a React.Fragment using the shorthand syntax "< >...< />" but when I try using "< React.Fragment>...< /React.Fragment>" I get an error saying that there is an exppected '}' character at the end of my else statement. What the heck is that about?

Please excuse and spacing errors in my code snippets and React tags. I couldn't figure out how to get them to display without adding additional spaces and I am almost entirely sure that this is not a syntax error but feel free to prove me wrong if that is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> onClick={this.props.navButtons[i].click()}

In your first take at a click event, react is evaluating the property when it's mounting the component. This causes `.click()` to be called immediately. There are two ways to fix this. One would be to just drop the brackets so that you are not executing your click handler immediately `.click`. The other option would be to have the click handler return another function (see final example).

> onClick={() => button.click()} title={button.title}

In your second try, you pass in an anonymous method which calls your `.click()`. In this case react evaluates the value which is a function and then saves it. React will then call this function when the event is triggered.

Bonus Points! Sometimes you want to have a value (like an index from a loop) which is used in your click handler. However, when you go to trigger the event it has the wrong value. You can fix this by calling a function which returns a function. It will then allow you to scope that value properly so it's there when you need it.

```
myThings.map((x, i) => <thing onClick={this.handleClick(i)} />

handleClick = (index: number) => () => {
   alert(index);
}
```

What happens in this example is handleClick is executed on mount seems how it is not wrapped within a function. It takes in the index number and then returns another function which is stored for that click handler. When any of the events get called they have kept a copy of the index value in their scope so you can have access to it.

Comment: Thanks!. This makes sense and seems to be what I was missing. Once I get a chance to test it to make sure I understand everything, I'll accept your answer.